# Contextual filter for hierarchal taxonomy with duplicate term names

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-contextual-filters

I have a taxonomy that has duplicate term names with different parents; for example

mens (tid=39) has child term shirts (tid=117) and
womens (tid=43) has child term shirts (tid=129)

The Contextual filter not working in this case but if change womens -> shirts to womens -> wshirts it start working. I tried all the possible combination for Contextual filter but nothing is working.

Found same issue on drupal [Drual Link][https://www.drupal.org/node/2641204] as well but no solution.